# How to make the cache re-access the evicted data?

Tags: gem5

I am trying to make the last level cache ( **Classic cache model, not Ruby**) re-access some of the evicted cache lines after a period of time (when the CPU does not currently request those cache lines), but I noticed that all the data requests are made from the CPU core via packets. Is this still achievable?

If that is possible to implement, should I create a new packet from the last level cache and send it to the main memory? Or possibly prefetch the evicted cache lines after the cache eviction is done?

Can someone give me some suggestions about this? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a prefetcher. Check if any of the existing prefetchers (src/mem/cache/prefetch/) does what you want; otherwise, you will have to add your own. I think you will have to do the latter option, as, IIRC, they don't observe evictions.

Your prefetcher needs 2 things:

1. *It must be made aware when an eviction happens, and observe the address that has been evicted.*
2. *It should generate prefetch requests for the evicted blocks you want.*

For *1*, it should be straightforward to listen to the data update probe (The cache's `ppDataUpdate` member) so that your prefetcher becomes able to observe evictions. An eviction happens when the `DataUpdate` contents are: `oldData` not empty, and `newData` empty. See the `FrequentValues` compressor for an example of how to listen to that probe.

Finally, for *2*, your new prefetcher should override `calculatePrefetch()`. See the `Tagged` prefetcher for a simple example.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much for the reply! I think your suggestions are very reasonable. I will have a try.